# Numpy array slicing using None and colon:

Tags: python

I am trying to understand how slicing works in numpy.

```
A = np.array([0, 1])
B = np.array([0, 1])
B = B[:, None]

print(A[None, :] == B[:, None])
```

The code in python gives

```
[[[ True False]]

 [[False  True]]]
```

Would someone be able to help explain why that is so?

Answer (score 1):

Because `B = B[:, None]` changes the array to 2d:

```
A = np.array([0, 1])
B = np.array([0, 1])
C = B[:, None]
print(B, C, sep='\n')
```

Output:

```
[0 1]
[[0]
 [1]]
```

They become different.

Also:

```
>>> A[:, None]
array([[0],
       [1]])
>>> A[None, :]
array([[0, 1]])
>>>
```

Aren't the same.

`[:, None]` makes it into a shape of `(2, 1)`, where `[None, :]` makes it into `(1, 2)`.

That's the difference, one transposes columns-wise, and one transposes row-wise.

Also for checking equality it becomes checking from `A[:, None]`, with:

```
array([[0, 0],
       [1, 1]])
```

And for `A[None, :]` it checks for:

```
array([[0, 1],
       [0, 1]])
```

So the first list row would be `[True, False]`, because `0 == 0` but `0 != 1`. And for the second row it would be `[False, True]`, because `1 != 0` but `1 == 1`.

Answer (score 1):

when you write `B[:, None]` you change `B` to `shape=(2,1)` and each element place in one row and when you write `A[None, :]` you change `A` to `shape=(1,2)` and each element place in one column see:

```
B = np.array([0, 1])
B = B[:, None]
#[[0]
# [1]]
A = A[None , :]
# array([[0, 1]])
```

then:

```
[B[0][0] == A[0][0] , B[0][0] == A[0][1]]
# True , False
[B[1][0] == A[0][0] , B[1][0] == A[0][1]]
# Fale  True
```